# Faster way to subtract columns and update row values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Faster way to subtract columns and update row values?

```
colSet1 = list(range(20))
colSet2 = list(range(21,40))
colSet3 = list(range(41,60))
for col1 in colSet1:
    for col2 in colSet2:
        for col3 in colSet3:
            df[col1+col2+col3+"_newcol"] = df[col1+col2+col3]-df[col1]
```

I tried `rsub` but it seems to give wrong results, not sure, if i implemented it correctly. What is the correct way to use rsub in this case, If that is the fastest way?

Comment: The loop has inter-iteration dependencies. It does not seem like you can vectorize it.

Comment: @DYZ Sorry, i made a mistake in providing the dummy code. I changed the column names in colSet2 and colSet3...They are not same, Please check updated dummy code, really sorry.

Comment: Does your code iterate over *all* the columns in `df`, or just some small fraction of them?

Comment: just a small fraction. In my original code, df has 3000 columns, and the loop updates 250 columns. Just wrote this dummy code to help other people easily understand it

Comment: I'm wondering if you can mask out the subset of all columns you want to subtract from and just do `subset - df[col1]` for each in `colSet1`.  Then you'd have a single loop instead of a triple-nested one.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: in your sample code you set colSet1, colSet2 and colSet3 as lists of integers, I'm assuming that what you meant is lists of strings since you're doing strings concatenation in the last line.*

As I first step I'd suggest using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) rather than nested loops for better performance:

```
for col1, col2, col3 in itertools.product(colSet1, colSet2, colSet3):
    df[col1+col2+col3 + "_newcol"] = df[col1+col2+col3] - df[col1]
```

or cleaner IMO:

```
for cols in itertools.product(colSet1, colSet2, colSet3):
    comb_col = ''.join(cols)
    df[comb_col + "_newcol"] = df[comb_col] - df[cols[0]]
```

The faster solution would be to vectorize your code and avoid updating the dataframe in pure python loops, it may look like this ***(NON TESTED, just to illustrate the idea)***:

```
import numpy as np
combinations = list(itertools.product(colSet1, colSet2, colSet3))

comb_cols = np.array([''.join(cols) for cols in combinations])
first_cols = [cols[0] for cols in combinations]

df[comb_cols + "_newcol"] = df[comb_cols] - df[first_cols]
```